# Navigation bar not resizing to browser screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the link to my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/81scw7eg/

MY JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
/* Stick the #bottomMenuBarContent to the top of the window */
var nav = $('#bottomMenuBarContent');
var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
var isFixed = false;
var $w = $(window);
$w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
        nav.css( {
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: nav.offset().left,
            width: nav.width()
        });
        isFixed = true;
    } else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed) {
        nav.css({
            position: 'static'
        });
        isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});

/* Changes Navigation Bar Color on Scroll */
$(document).ready(function(){
var scroll_pos = 0;
$(document).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scroll_pos > 50) {
        $("#bottomMenuBarContent").css('background-color', '#2a2a2a');
    } else {
        $("#bottomMenuBarContent").css('background-color', 'grey');
    }
});
});
```

I don't know why, but my navigation bar isn't resizing to my screen. Try opening up my site and resizing it to a smaller size. Now scroll down on the website so that the navigation bar changes colors, and then maximize the browser screen. For some reason it doesn't move along with it. Any ideas why?

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deuxl.png)

Comment: Hey there, please don't put your JSFiddle link inside a code snippet - make it an actual hyperlink. And if the form complains that you should include your code with a JSFiddle link...then please do. Questions should be self-contained, they shouldn't rely solely on external resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example you set the width of the element to it's original width
(which is in this case made by it's content and which doesn't go 100% of the screen the moment you switch from position: static to position: fixed)

just replace the line

```
width: nav.width()
```

with

```
right: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there are any good tutorials on making websites online? Trying to learn so when next semester hits I can be prepared.

Comment: there are several tutorials. just google and try to figure out. cant name a specific one cause my native language is german and I did a lot of these tutorials.

but you should know the basics of HTML (defining the content), CSS (mostly defining the outward appearance) and JavaScript (defining the websites behavior and interaction)
If you get deeper into it you will learn about HTML 5 (newest iterartion of html), CSS helpers like SCSS or less, and helpful JavaScript Frameworks like jQuery.

And one more thing: there is enough tutorials and references on the internet. no need to buy a book.